# Prove that the function $f(x)=e^{ax}$ is continuous on $(- \infty, \infty)$ using $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that the function $f(x)=e^{ax}$ is continuous on $(- \infty, \infty)$. Take the following properties as given:
>   $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 1$$
>   $$ f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1)f(x_2), - \infty<x_1,x_2<\infty$$

I am updating my understanding:

$f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$, $\forall x_0 \in (a,b)$ we have

$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$

For every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$$

$$|f(x+x_0-x_0)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$$
$$|f(x_0)[ f(x-x_0)-1] |< \epsilon$$
$$ |e^{a(x-x_0)}-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{e^{ax_0}}$$
$$|a(x-x_0)| < ln(\frac{\epsilon}{e^{ax_0}}+1)$$
$$|x-x_0|< \frac{1}{a} \cdot ln(\frac{\epsilon}{e^{ax_0}}+1)$$

Is this correct? How do I complete the proof?
much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Simply note that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(f(x)(f(h)-1)\right)\\\\
&=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\left(f(h)-1\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

---

EDIT:
The OP edited the question to request a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.  To proceed, we use the elementary inequalities

$$1+x\le e^x \le \frac1{1-x} \tag1 $$

for $x<1$.

First, we write

$$\left| e^{a(x+h)}-e^{ax}\right| = e^{ax}\left|e^{ah}-1\right|$$

Then, using $(1)$ we see that for $1>ah>0$

$$e^{ax}\left|e^{ah}-1\right|\le \frac{ah}{1-ah}\,e^{ax}<\epsilon$$

whenever $|h|<\frac{\epsilon e^{-ax}}{|a|(1+e^{-ax})}$.

For $ah<0$, we see that

$$e^{ax}\left|e^{ah}-1\right|\le e^{ax}|ah|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|h|<\frac{\epsilon e^{ax}}{|a|}$.

Comment: @Mark Viola, thx for the input. Could you elaborate on how you go from $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} (f(h+h) - f(x))$ to $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} (f(x)(f(h) - 1)$? Also I dont see the connection with the original function $e^{ax}$, I understand that $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h) =1$ as it is given.

Comment: @gegu Isn't $f(x)$ equal to $e^{ax}$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just do not understand the logical sequence of Mark's method, I dont have in my book any model such as the one of Mark to help me connecting my understanding. Using what I know, I updated my preliminary steps any chance is correct.

Comment: @MarkViola yes it has been corrected. Question regarding your model: you take the limit at 0, How does this prove that it is continuous on all the domain? I change my preliminary work, any chance I am going in the right direction?

Comment: @sranthrop  I change my preliminary work, any chance I am going in the right direction?

Comment: @gegu a function is continuous at a point $x_0$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x)-f(x_0)=0$ .Mark puts $h=x-x_0$ which goes to zero as $x$ goes to $x_0$, thus $f(x)=f(x_0+h) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.You can use an epsilon argument using this fact and taking $|h|< \delta$. Mark's idea is correct.You can just fill in the gaps with the epsilon argument.It's not difficult at all.